# What is the difference between the following c++ constructors?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I've seen c++ class constructors initialize members in two different ways, but with the same effect. Suppose we have a simple class:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myclass();//default constructor

private:
    int a;
    int b;
    bool c;
};
```

Case 1:

```
myClass::myClass()
/* Default constructor */
{
    a=5;
    b=10;
    c=true;

    //do more here
}
```

Case 2:

```
myClass::myClass()
/* Default constructor */

    :a(5),
    b(10),
    c(true)
{
    //do more in here
}
```

What is the difference between the two after it compiles? Even if there is no difference, is there a "preferred" way of doing it?

Comment: No difference as both do the same thing. Preference is up to you to decide. Personnally I prefer the second one

Comment: whenever possible prefer case 2. Using initialization list is always optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First constructor calls default constructor of `a,b,c` first(basically assign them to random value) then assigns them to the provided value. Second constructor directly calls the appropriate constructors for `a,b,c`.

In general, second constructor is more efficient as members are initialized once, also if you have members without default constructor, you have to initialize them that way or with non-static member initializer in C++11.

Comment: combine that with the fact that some types *can't* be reassigned, and it becomes clear that the second approach is far better